# How to check if a string or multiple strings exists within an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I know this question has been asked on this platform, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I want to check if one or more strings exist in an array but it is giving me false when I checked.

```
$a1 = array('J.S.S 1','J.S.S 2','J.S.S 3','S.S 1','S.S 2','S.S 3','Primary One','Primary Two','Primary Three','Primary Four','Primary Five','Primary Six');

$b1 = 'S.S 2','S.S 3'
```

So, I put variable $b1 in array

```
$b1 = array($b1)
```

And used **in_array** to check if $b1 exist in $a1

```
if (in_array($b1,$a1)) {
  echo "TRUE";
}
else{
  echo "FALSE";
}
```

It returns `FALSE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be it'll be useful for you http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: `$b1 = 'S.S 2','S.S 3'` This is wrong, would throw a fatal syntax error. Could you please correct it so its clearer what you mean?

Comment: @yivi, Thanks for your help. **S.S 2,S.S 3** was actually from the DB before I implode it to make it **'S.S 2','S.S 3'**. Still no luck.

Comment: It's still not clear. Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54868126/edit) your question to show exactly your code. If your the code in your question doesn't match what you are using, it's harder to help you. So there shoudn't be any syntax errors in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, while [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54868126/edit) please mention if you are looking for a complete match (e.g. all elements of $b1 have to exist on $a1), or a partial match (some elements of $b1 exist on $a1).

Answer (score 1):

> $b1 = 'S.S 2','S.S 3' // Thats a syntax error
>
> $b1 = array($b1) // You can't make an array out of a broken string

You can solve this by iterating through the `$b1` array and check if any of the strings in `$b1` are found inside `$a1` with a combination of `foreach` and `in_array`:

https://3v4l.org/Z4N6j

```
$a1 = array('J.S.S 1','J.S.S 2','J.S.S 3','S.S 1','S.S 2','S.S 3','Primary One','Primary Two','Primary Three','Primary Four','Primary Five','Primary Six');

$b1 = ['S.S 2','S.S 3'];

$found = false;
foreach($b1 as $b) {
    if(in_array($b, $a1)) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($found);
```

Edit as per echmel's comment:

An alternative solution using `array_intersect`:

https://3v4l.org/YfhC6

```
function test(array $input1, array $input2): bool {
    $result = array_intersect($input1,$input2);
    $result = count($result) > 0;

    return $result;
}

test([1,2,3],[1,2]);
```

Comment: It returned false

Comment: @wealthouseinfo Probably because the elements are not in the array then?... As you can see it works just fine in the 3v4l (with the same input data as you provided.)

Comment: @wealthouseinfo The above code results in `true`.  If you are getting `false`, then you are doing something different.